# How to extract data from a list in SharePoint using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, sharepoint, raphael, extract

I'm trying to extract data from a list in my private Sharepoint, My list has 3 Columns: ID | PieCategory | PieNumber and 12 Values. I found this code on the development center [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/hh185007%28v=office.14%29.aspx). And for some reason even if it appears so simple, something isn't working. I have checked by writing:

```
alert('Test');
```

It's all good on that side, so there must be something wrong either with my list or with the code here below. I'm not particularly attached to this code, if there is a better/easiest way I'll take it! I've tried other codes that I've written below and none (with the current setting I've written work).

```
var siteUrl = '/sites/MyPersonalSite';
function retrieveListItems() {
var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext(siteUrl);
var oList = clientContext.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle('pieChart'); 
//This is my list '/sites/MyPersonalSite/Lists/pieChart/AllItems.aspx'

var camlQuery = new SP.CamlQuery();
camlQuery.set_viewXml('<View><Query><Where><Geq><FieldRef Name=\'ID\'/>' + 
    '<Value Type=\'Number\'>1</Value></Geq></Where></Query><RowLimit>2</RowLimit></View>');
this.collListItem = oList.getItems(camlQuery);
// It was originally set to 10 but moved it to 2 and I have 12 observations so it should be enough

clientContext.load(collListItem);

clientContext.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQuerySucceeded), Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQueryFailed));        
    }
function onQuerySucceeded(sender, args) {

var listItemInfo = '';

var listItemEnumerator = collListItem.getEnumerator();

while (listItemEnumerator.moveNext()) {
    var oListItem = listItemEnumerator.get_current();
    listItemInfo += '\nID: ' + oListItem.get_id() + 
        '\nCategory: ' + oListItem.get_item('PieCategory') + 
        '\nValue: ' + oListItem.get_item('PieNumber');
}

alert(listItemInfo.toString());
}
function onQueryFailed(sender, args) {

alert('Request failed. ' + args.get_message() + '\n' + args.get_stackTrace());
}
```

The second Code that I miserably tried to implement.

```
function retrieveListItems() {

var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext('/sites/MyPersonalSite');
var oList = clientContext.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle('pieChart');

var camlQuery = new SP.CamlQuery();
camlQuery.set_viewXml('<View><Query><Where><Leq>' + 
    '<FieldRef Name=\'ID\'/><Value Type=\'Number\'>10</Value>' + 
    '</Leq></Where></Query><RowLimit>5</RowLimit></View>');

this.collListItem = oList.getItems(camlQuery);

clientContext.load(collListItem, 'Include(ID, PieNumber, PieCategory)');

clientContext.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQuerySucceeded), Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQueryFailed));        
    }
function onQuerySucceeded(sender, args) {

var listItemInfo = '';

var listItemEnumerator = collListItem.getEnumerator();

while (listItemEnumerator.moveNext()) {
    var oListItem = listItemEnumerator.get_current();
    listItemInfo += '\nID: ' + oListItem.get_id() + 
        '\nDisplay name: ' + oListItem.get_PieNumber() +
        '\nCategory: ' +oListItem.get_PieCategory();
}

alert(listItemInfo.toString());
}

function onQueryFailed(sender, args) {

alert('Request failed. ' + args.get_message() + '\n' + args.get_stackTrace());
}
```

I know there are ways of doing this by C# but I can only do it on JavaScript as I'm trying to roll this out into a Graph from gRaphael and I'm trying to keep it quite simple for future use.

Comment: When using the second one, I get an alert (which is already something) and it says: Request failed: column 'PieCategory' does not exist. But it is there, so it's not recognizing it for some reason

Comment: In your first attempt try following view xml:
<View><Query><Where><Geq><FieldRef Name=\'ID\'/><Value Type=\'Number\'>1</Value></Geq></Where></Query><RowLimit>2</RowLimit><ViewFields><FieldRef Name=\'PieNumber\' /><FieldRef Name=\'PieCategory\'/></ViewFields></View>

Comment: Also are you sure that "PieCategory" and "PieNumber" are static names of your fields?

Comment: You can install Firefox and the addon "Firebug" to check the request sent to the server and the response from it. You'll see the possible error messages.
Also the native functions from Microsoft are very difficult to use and not clear at all. You may want to try http://aymkdn.github.io/SharepointPlus/ that is doing the hard job with a simple API.

Comment: it was the static names -  got it sort it!! thank you so much @Yeygeiny.Chernobrivets